# Intercepting XMLHttpRequest and setRequestHeader appending values

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I am trying to use the below code to intercept some AJAX calls from my app (which uses both axios and fetch).

```
(function(send) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
            this.setRequestHeader('someHeader', 'ABC');
            send.call(this, data);
        };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

However, each execution of this line setRequestHeader seems to be appending the values and setting in the header.

E.g. if I have 3 AJAX calls on my page, for the 3rd request, I see "user" header value as "ABC ABC ABC"

Not sure if the above way is correct ?

Comment: I just tried that code locally, and I don't see that behavior. I see just `user: ABC` in the requests, even the third one. Sounds like the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Also works on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-69851265-x0ky8?file=/main.js.

Comment: yes that seems a bit strange...actually in place of the value i.e. 'ABC', I have a variable there and I tried adding console for that variable and strangely it just prints ABC each time...which is why I suspect something to do with setRequestHeader

Comment: Just noticed on this page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader), it says 
Each time you call setRequestHeader() after the first time you call it, the specified text is appended to the end of the existing header's content.

Comment: Yeah, but that's on a given XHR object. Presumably each of your ajax calls uses a new XHR object. (I don't think you can reuse them. Even if you could, it wouldn't be a good idea. :-) )